# Deixar um campo do BordePane transparente Javafx

Tags: javafx

Bom dia, estou a tentar fazer com que apenas um dos componentes de um BorderPane fique com o aspecto de transparente. Nesse caso eu utilizei o .opacity, porem foi no stage.

Código que criei:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("App.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setOpacity(0.5);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

E essa é a imagem de exemplo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que apenas a parte em azul fique transparent e não todo o programa, já tentei um opacity dentro do FXML na parte em que quero deixar transparent, porem não foi o resultado obtido, pois ele apenas deixa a parte num aspecto mais claro.

Comment: Pode ser que ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663681/javafx-effect-on-background

Comment: Cara obrigado pela resposta, foi a mesma que achei ao assistir um video no youtube de inspiracoes javafx.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri como.

colocando apenas:

```
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

com isso sua app vai ficar transparente, mas ao editar o .fxml e por outros node e por uma cor e por opacidade nesse node ele vai ter o efeito desejado.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]